# Next-js: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

i am trying to render React element in root/components folder, and get:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

this is the import of my element:

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```

this is my toast function:

```
...
toast.success(<div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{msg}</div>, {
        theme: "colored",
      })
...
```

and this is what am trying to do:

```
//root/components/Footer/index.js
const Footer = () => {
   return(
   ...
      <ToastContainer
      position="bottom-center"
      autoClose={3000}
      hideProgressBar={false}
      newestOnTop={false}
      closeOnClick
      rtl={false}
      pauseOnFocusLoss
      draggable
      pauseOnHover
      theme="dark"
    />
   ...
);
}
export default Footer;
```

any help?

Comment: What does your entire toast function look like? Where is `{msg}` defined? Any indication which of your files the error is coming from?

Comment: ignore {msg}, replace it with plain text.
errors come when i put <ToastContainer .../>.
toast function is a build-in function from 'react-toastify' plugin.

Comment: Where/how are you importing `Footer`?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple [working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-18-2-react-toastify-kt6vn1) of `react-toastify` using the code you provided. It seems like you're either importing `Footer` wrong and should explore the file that imports that OR this error is from some other component you haven't shown here.

**src/App.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

export default function App() {
  const successToast = () => {
    toast.success(
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <span>Success Toast</span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const baseToast = () => {
    toast(
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <span>Base Toast</span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={successToast}>Success Toast</button>
      <button onClick={baseToast}>Base Toast</button>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**src/components/Footer/index.js**

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <ToastContainer
      position="bottom-center"
      autoClose={3000}
      hideProgressBar={false}
      newestOnTop={false}
      closeOnClick
      rtl={false}
      pauseOnFocusLoss
      draggable
      pauseOnHover
      theme="dark"
    />
  );
};
export default Footer;
```